# How to free a binary tree using C?

Tags: c, memory-management

I have written a binary search tree, it works fine but I'm not sure whether my program frees all the memories.

here is my definition of the node of a tree

```
typedef struct node  {
    int val;
    struct node *left, *right;
} nodeOfTree;
```

I write this function to output the result and free all the nodes, it seems that the answer is right but the memories are not freed.

```
void outputAndDestroyTree(nodeOfTree *root)  {
    if (!root) {return;}
    outputAndDestroyTree(root->left);
    printf("%d ", root->val);
    outputAndDestroyTree(root->right);
    free(root);      // I free this pointer, but after doing that, I can still access this  pointer in the main() function
}
```

Is that mean I can not free a piece of memories in the recursive function? Thank you ~~~~~

Update: Thank you all~

Comment: How do you know the memory is not freed? Free doesn't mean the data has to be overwritten, if that's what you expect.

Comment: By `free`, you are not destroying something. The memory region and data is still there, marked `not used`.

Comment: If you store tree nodes within a pre-allocated chunk of memory, you can *destroy* the entire tree with a single `free()`. Sort of simple memory management. But as others have already pointed out, `free` does not wipe out the content of the *freed* memory -- just makes it available for other allocations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code seems okay, but freeing the allocated memory won't magically set it's reference pointer to `NULL`. Since you didn't set a new value to the pointer, the old address will remain there, untouched. Maybe you can even read from it without crashing, despite it being undefined behavior.

If you want it to be set to `NULL` after freeing the memory, then just do so. Call `outputAndDestroyTree(root->left);` then do `root->left = NULL;`.